# JSON PUT request using Slim framework

Tags: php, json, slim

I am trying to make a PUT request to Slim using the following code:

```
 <script type = "text/javascript">
 function submitform() {
   var url = '/users/' + $('#user_id').val();
   $('#myform').attr('action', url);
   var data = JSON.stringify({"value": $('#user_data').val()});
   $('<input type="hidden" name="json"/>').val(data).appendTo('#myform');
   $("#myform").submit();
   }
 </script>

 <form id = "myform" method="post">
 id:   <input type = "text" id = "user_id">
 data: <input type = "text" name = "value" id = "user_data">
 <input type="hidden" name="_METHOD" value="PUT"/>
 <input type = "button" value = "submit" onClick='submitform()'>
 </form>
```

My index.php file contains:

```
$app->put('/users/:id', 'update');
function update($id) {
  $jsonmessage = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
  $message = json_decode($jsonmessage->getBody());
  // what do I put here ????
  }
```

What should I put in place of the ???? to retrieve the value parameter.
I can see it if I use $_POST['json'] but I don't think this is REST compliant.
Everything else I've tried, such as $message->value, doesn't work (returns nothing).

Thanks.

UPDATE:

Somebody from the Slim forum provided the following answer:

```
$json = $jsonmessage->put('json');
$message = json_decode($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the parameter of your `JSON` put request, then there is a simple solution in Slim.

```php
//$app->request()->params('parameterKey');
$params = $app->request()->params('value');
```

I think I got your question and let me know if it solves.

Answer (score 0):

$message->value

json_decode will create a standard php object for you.  You can also try var_dump($message) to see the structure of the object for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I use the below code to pull the request body

```
$request = Slim::getInstance()->request();
$user = json_decode($request->getBody());
```